# Error timeout after 5000 ms with mongoose jest and superuser

Tags: mongodb, express, testing, mongoose, jestjs

Im trying to test an endpoint using jest,supertest and mongoose, but actually when i try to do a request using supertest it gaves an error of timeout after 5000 ms that the async callback was not invoked

```
// test.js
import supertest from 'supertest';
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

import app from '../../src/index';
import user from '../../src/app/models/user';

const request = supertest(app);

beforeAll(async () => {
  await mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/user', {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
  });
});

it('should list all user', async (done) => {
  const response = await request.get('/');
  expect(response.status).toBe(200);

  done();
});

//index.js
import express from 'express';
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import routes from './routes';

const app = express();

// mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/usersexample', {
//   useNewUrlParser: true,
//   useUnifiedTopology: true,
// });

app.use(express.json());
app.use(routes);

app.listen(3000);

export default app;
```

Answer (score 0):

You did not provide enough information, because of the error you are calling a route that has no answer, jest is looking for an end but as he has no or has not found it ends up running infinitely.

Comment: actually im using routes and at routes.js it has an endpoint for '/' so that should complete, shouln't it?

Comment: no, you need to complete the answer, I don't know which library you are using, if you have the "/" route and need it in the case of express for example, you would need to pass the status and the closing response as a .send()